# To pass a parameter form one jsp page to another using Onclick

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I need to pass the id parameter from `task.jsp` to `edit.jsp`.

I tried using the set and get parameter with input type as hidden, but was unable to get the id in the edit.jsp

This is a part of my task.jsp page

```
<tr>
                <%-- <td><%=currentTask.getId()%></td> --%>
                <td><%=currentTask.getTaskDescription()%></td>
                <td><%=currentTask.getDate()%></td>
                <td><%=currentTask.getUser().getUserName()%></td>
                <td><input id="<%=currentTask.getId()%>" type="button"
                    onclick="editAction(this)" value="Edit" /></td>
                <td><input id="<%=currentTask.getId()%>" type="button"
                    onclick="deleteAction(this)" value="Delete" /></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p />
    <input type="button"
        onclick="window.location='/HibernateWebApp/login.jsp';"
        value="Logout">

    <%
        System.out.println(userName);
    %>
</form>
<b><a href="CreateTask.jsp?userName=${userName}"> Click here
        to add a new task </a></b>


<script>
    function editAction(item) {
        int id = item.id;
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
<script>
    document.getElementById("id").value = id;
        document.form.action = "edit.jsp";
        document.form.submit();
        console.log(item.id);
    }
</script>


<script>
    function deleteAction(item) {
        console.log(item.id);
    }
</script>
```

This is the error I get in my console when I click on the edit button - `ReferenceError: editAction is not defined`

How do I pass the parameter from task.jsp and get it is edit.jsp

Comment: I'm not sure it works by splitting a function definition over multiple script blocks. Why don't you just create the hidden input somewhere on the page or add it to the form via javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something likewise either way...

**task.jsp**

```
<a href="t1.jsp?val=<%=currentTask.getId()%>">Edit</a>

    <!-- OR -->

    <form action="edit.jsp" method="post">
        <input id="id_anything123" type="hidden" name="val" value="<%=currentTask.getId()%>" />
        <input id="<%=currentTask.getId()%>" type="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
```

**edit.jsp**

```
 <%= request.getParameter("val") %> <!-- will print value which you have pass from task.jsp -->
```

Comment: the anchor tag answer is working fine, but the button is not working I have already given an action before my table with post method, hence on clicking the button the control is navigating to that part

Comment: @ShashiKiran see again i updated my asnwer. for <form> tag use POST method then do according as per my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and I found this way to do :

In the html :

```
<button><a href="ServletName?id=${UserName}">ButtonName</a></button>
```

In the servlet :

```
request.getParameter("id");
```